# How can I check XElements for null vals in a way that Resharper will accept?

Tags: c#, resharper, nullreferenceexception, xelement

Even when I wear suspenders, R# tells me I need a belt. I had code like this:

```
private static ItemGroup GetItemGroupsForXMLElement(XElement itemGroup)
{
    return new ItemGroup
    {
        Id = Convert.ToInt32(itemGroup.Element("Id").Value),
        item_group_id = itemGroup.Element("item_group_id").Value,
        name = itemGroup.Element("name").Value
    };
}
```

...which R# complained about, saying it was potentially catastrophic and that reigning NREs could rain down upon my noggin; IOW, I needed to rein them in before they got to that point.

So I added code to test the data elements for nullness and retreat if any were (null):

```
private static ItemGroup GetItemGroupsForXMLElement(XElement itemGroup)
{
    var IdElement = itemGroup.Element("Id");
    var item_group_idElement = itemGroup.Element("item_group_id");
    var nameElement = itemGroup.Element("name");
    if ((null == IdElement) || (null == item_group_idElement) || 
        (null == nameElement)) return null;
    return new ItemGroup
    {
        Id = Convert.ToInt32(itemGroup.Element("Id").Value),
        item_group_id = itemGroup.Element("item_group_id").Value,
        name = itemGroup.Element("name").Value
    };
}
```

...but that still doesn't appease R#; I still get beaucoup "Possible 'System.NullReferenceException"s. Apparently, it doesn't see that the various Elements have already been tested for null, and I only get to the "return new ItemGroup" block of code if all is well that way.

How can I test these elements for null in a way that R# recognizes that I have done so?

Comment: Is it complaining because `itemGroup` could be null?

Comment: It warns about each element possibly being null. Selman, Alabama's solution works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use explicit cast instead of accessing the `Value` property

```
return new ItemGroup
{
    Id = (int)itemGroup.Element("Id"),
    item_group_id = (string)itemGroup.Element("item_group_id"),
    name = (string)itemGroup.Element("name")
};
```